# How to change the text to bold and color in survey in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-server, survey-list

I want to get the text bold and underline and want to change some text to red color I am trying like the below code but still not changing anything

```
<script src="/../IT/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   if($(this).html() == ("1.  This online survey is used to find out how many staff will be interested to attend the Onsite Health Screening"))
{
  ($(this)).html("Yes, I would like to attend the FREE Onsite Basic Health Screening at <U><B> JI Site Office on 16 August 2016 </B></U> (please proceed to Q2)");
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use bold tag in html text see example below:

```
$(this).html("Yes, I would like to attend the FREE Onsite Basic Health Screening at  <b>JI Site Office on 16 August 2016 </b>  (please proceed to Q2)")
```

Comment: I tried like this only it dint reflect... is there any solution for this ?

Comment: it should work, i have tried and tested it. What is this in your case, is that an element

Comment: $(this).css("color","red");

Comment: Hi @AnkitKumar $(this).css("color","red"); this is not reflecting is there any method to approach

Comment: I want to change only "please procced to Q2" to red

Comment: <style color="red"><label>please proceed to Q2</label></style>